# Is .xdp file dependent on hardware IBM RTRT tool

Tags: rtrt

I'm new to RTRT tool. I want to configure a TDP for a new hardware. While creating the TDP I require a .xdp file. So, my question is whether the .xdp file is dependent on hardware? If yes, then from where will I get the .xdp file?

Answer (score 0):

XDP i.e., the target deployment port is hardware specific. You will have to edit this as per your need in RTRT which basically has all the settings you need to run your project on. In the target deployment port editor you can edit/create the .xdp file as per your need.